# Module threading doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to make 2 functions that will be executed at the same moment and when I run the code it returns "NameError: name 'Thread' is not defined" even though I fully imported the threading module. Here is a bit of my code:

```
from threading import *
from time import time, sleep

def one(num):
    sleep(num)

def two(num):
    sleep(num)

t1 = Thread(target=one, args=(1,))
t2 = Thread(target=two, args=(1,))

x1 = time()

t1.start()
t2.start()

x2 = time()

print(x2-x1)
```

upd1: I'm using python 3.9.5 on linux mint cinnamon

upd2: The code works perfectly fine in windows but not on linux

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Pasting that same code into an `asdftest.py` and running it works fine.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: As an aside, there's no such thing as "fully importing"; in general star imports are not good form, since they usually bring in many more symbols than you really need.

Comment: @AKX: Good form or no, you seem to have understood what "fully importing" meant, it being another term for a "star import", which apparently is a "thing".

Comment: FYI, After you get your `import` problem fixed, that `print` call is going to tell you how much time it took to _start_ the two threads. Changing the amount of time that each of the threads spend sleeping will have no definite effect on the number that is printed. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Also, what is the point of having two different functions, `one` and `two`, that both do exactly the same thing? Why don't you just use the same function for both threads?